# Do abstract ideas exist or are they only to be found in language?

Tags: ontology, philosophy-of-language

Is there any reason to imagine that abstract ideas exist when they are nowhere to be found except in language?

No more is known today, for example, about Platonic Forms than upon initial utterance some 2500+ years ago. Metaphysical speculations and justifications simply have not provided the conception with any heuristic merit and as of yet, not a one has been observed or confirmed.

As another example: all points equidistant from a single point upon a two dimensional plane, i.e. a Euclidian circle, can not be observed in the world (from all that we can observer between the scope of quantum decoherence to cosmological and epistemically opaque whole ("black holes"). There are, however, innumerable instances of things which can be described as circular. Be this a limitation of spacetime or due to the use and definition of "point", it seems to me that the only place a Euclidian circle can be found is in its description (language).

Unless we are to imagine that describing a unicorn amounts to invoking its "existence" in the same sense that the computer screens which you and I are viewing this on exist, I think the answer is plainly "no, abstract ideas are only to be found in language".

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Your question is about the ages old problem of universals, and the position you favor is called nominalism https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalism The opposite position is called realism, there are various other approaches and no definitive answer. There is a vast literature on the issue to which we can't usefully add something here without a more specific question. See our help center on how to ask http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Conifold. I've always thought "realism" a funny way of expressing that view. I'd counter, however, that 1) I was addressing the ambiguity of the term "exists" and 2) that metaphysical views are irrelevant to philosophy. What can be known of abstract ideas except that they do not exist and are only to be found in language?

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow. Right after saying that metaphysical views are irrelevant you ask a question presupposing a metaphysical view. The  ambiguity of "existence" was addressed many times over in the debate on universals also, so I still do not see what more we can add here.

Comment: "...irrelevant to philosophy." Metaphysics are little more than the works by Aristotle as categorized by Andronicus of Rhodes. If you mean meta-physics, then all that can be discussed is language (physical acoustic blasts and symbols *about* physics), otherwise how can anyone know what is meant by your use of "metaphysics"?

Comment: I think you're exactly right -- it depends on your definition (or maybe just connotation rather than denotation) of "exist".  Ideas, abstract or concrete, are ultimately "electrochemical patterns in your brain". So if you say that, e.g., a piece of paper cut into a circular shape means "circles exist", then ideas also exist. If not, then not.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Empirical verifiability is a "dangerous" requirement? No, it is a cornerstone of knowledge. While you may observe the circular, you do not observe Euclidian circles except in language. Quarks, while not directlly observed, are verifiable and predictions based on their existence have been confirmed. Of course I have not directly observed Napolean - if the past were observable it would be present - but pointing out that abstract ideas are only found in language is not a proposition that he was a fictional character.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA you say "slim" ontology as if it were bulimic. I counter that it is *focused* and *lean*. The importance of the "role" of abstract ideas is an issue for psychology, not philosophy. Here's a non-abstract (concrete) idea for you: "the computer screen you are looking at right now" - if the identifiers are too much for you to parse, how about "the Three Gorges Dam"?

Comment: What do you mean by "exist only in language"? Is the "language" part important? It's by no means settled that all human abstract thinking is through the medium of language. To give an obvious possible counterexample, people often try to mentally  "visualize" mathematical concepts.

Comment: @sumelic ..."found" only in language. "Existing" in language is metaphorical. A broad definition of language includes visualizing mathematical concepts. Are you suggesting that the visualization of mathematical concepts is an example of an abstract idea existing in the same way your keyboard exists - if so, how much does this idea weigh?

Comment: No, I was just not sure how much specificity you meant by "language." "Existing in visual thought "is distinct from "existing in the same way a computer screen exists," but it can also be distinguished from "existing in linguistic thought." For example, there are arguably things that can be expressed in language that cannot be visualized, such as "square circles" and other contradictory concepts.

Comment: @sumelic, I mean language broadly. Visual thought, arguably, has an irreducibly first person subjective ontology, and therefore exists as much as the person visualizing the thought does, but I think this is not the same as saying that the visualization or the content of the visualization "exists". Could mathematical concepts be visualized without language? I am skeptical that they could as math, like music, is a language, no?

Comment: @Conifold when you say "metaphysical" question do you mean "ontological" or are you referring to the [categorical strategy](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20123845?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) of Andronicus of Rhodes?

Comment: Your comment looked similar to the views of logical positivists like Carnap and Ayer concerning "elimination of metaphysics", to them "metaphysical" was close to neither analytic nor empirical. "Abstract ideas... are only to be found in language" is itself metaphysical in their sense (and so is their criterion for "metaphysical", as critics pointed out). I am not sure if Husserlian phenomenology qualifies as "metaphysical" since he was an anti-realist, but it entails rejection of your thesis, so does Peirce's pragmatism.

Comment: @Conifold, Oh. So what did **you** mean when *you* said I'd asked "a question presupposing a metaphysical view."?

Comment: That "What can be known of abstract ideas except that they do not exist and are only to be found in language?" presupposes a metaphysical view about abstract ideas, namely an eliminative one.

Comment: @Conifold again, what do *you* mean with your use of "a metaphysical view"? "An ontological view"? In that case, my claim is not at all eliminative, nor a "view" - it merely recognizes the domain of abstract ideas within the realm of language and correctly denies their existence (in the sense that the computer screen you are looking at exists or as Wisdom's "cheese on the table" [exists](https://sites.ualberta.ca/~francisp/NewPhil448/WisdomPhilPerplex36.pdf)). Do you mean "a metaphysical view" in the sense of Rhodes' categorical strategy? In that sense, I literally have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Without getting into generalities, denying existence of universals as entities, or asserting it for that matter, is a thesis about the "fundamental nature of being", and therefore is "metaphysical". I think this is more or less common usage, but I am not sure how it relates to the "categorical strategy".

Comment: Or is the statement you have described as "metaphysical" instead an epistemic statement regarding the obvious distinction of what is empirically verifiable and what is not? Still have no idea what *you* mean by "metaphysical" so instead of generalities how about specifics? E.g. does not "exist" suffice for whatever you mean by "the fundamental nature of being"? Aren't you presuming more than ontology and philosophy allow? By "metaphysics" do you perhaps mean "physics about physics" and isn't that just language?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48202/discussion-between-conifold-and-mr-kennedy).

Comment: @Conifold so much for chatting. "fundamental nature of" adds nothing to ontological inquiries regarding existence ("being"). Again, I still have no idea what *you* mean by "metaphysical" nor how stating an empirically verifiable and falsifiable fact "presupposes a metaphysical view". Your comment reads like an "eliminative" dismissal of something which does not fit your weltanschauung (view) as opposed to a constructive comment, counter-example or rejoinder.

Comment: "Abstract ideas" is an abstract idea. So, if they do not exist, what are we talking about?

Comment: @LuísHenrique descriptions. That cats exist or that a cat exists, the idea of or category of cats or "cattiness" is only to be found in language. The abstraction does not exist (unless you mean exist metaphorically). See again the distinction between an Euclidian circle and the circular.

Comment: You are arguing about semantics again. You are using too many words. I know I exist, and I don't need any words to know that I exist. Metaphysics simply means beyond physics, and thoughts are beyond the scope of physics. Philosophy encompasses all pursuits of knowledge, and so we can philosophize about metaphysics and physics in the same breath.

Answer (score 1):

I'll have to struggle with this for awhile, but let me get on with my initial agreement:

Abstract ideas are defined by the thinker who is capable of describing them. It is possible that this thinker may never use spoken language to share the idea but they must, in some form, use language to conceptualize it themselves. It may also be said that abstract ideas do not exist independently of their description. For example: physical objects, forces, and radiation all exist, but the words for them and the overarching term "Physics" does not exist independent of thought and language.

A part of me wants to say that some phenomena described by abstract ideas exist independent of their description. I just can't think of any examples right now -_-

Comment: Any further thoughts on the matter? I imagine that thought is a biologically causal process, but the idea thought of - is it in the neurons or just in the dalliance between utterer and audience?

Answer (score 0):

One can visualize abstract ideas. So, at the very least they exist inside the mind. It does not require language to visualize a perfect circle. I don't have to have a language to describe it. If I never met another being, I would still have an image in my mind of circles. There are things which are circular. The image in my mind might be an average of all circular objects I have seen. The image might be a symbol, to myself for myself, and thus a language of symbols which I use to categorize objects in my mind. However, the perfect circle now exists as a symbol in my mind.

Answer (score -1):

Is "the capability of the physical laws to build a machine that simulates Turing machines" an abstract idea? It sounds quite abstract to me.

It exists objectively, as there could be theoretically a universe without that. It has existed before human starts to think about that.

If you define that to be not abstract, it's quite likely you have defined "abstract" to be a specific type of the things not found outside languages. Then, by definition, it exists as an idea, and it doesn't exist physically, or anywhere that is not in languages. You can call that existing or not existing, but please choose in whatever ways the person listening to you could understand. Personally, I feel it quite awkward to say there is a processor that uses x86_64 instruction set while the instruction set itself doesn't exist.

Comment: And yet physical laws don't build machines.